# Need to parallel run a video on multiple hosts BASH

Tags: bash, wait, kill

So I have a for loop where

```
  for HOST in $HOST_LOOP
   do
     ssh $HOST ... play video ... &
  done
  wait
```

I wanted to play the video on those hosts at the same time, that's what the `&` is for and the wait is for the script to keep running. But when I try to exit the bashscript, the processes still run on the background and the video keeps playing. I want to kill the processes, and I know that an individual host kills the video by `ssh $Host pkill ffplay`

So how can I kill these processes? The thing really throwing me off is this `wait` because it has essentially nothing to wait for, and it's becoming an infinite loop...

Comment: `because it has essentially nothing to wait for` ? it has to wait for commands running in the background

Comment: BTW, note that `for HOST in $HOST_LOOP` is _itself_ bad practice. A list of hosts should be stored in an array, not a string (this would be iterated over with `for host in "${hosts[@]}"`), and all-caps names are reserved for variables with special meaning to the shell itself (if you use lowercase for your own variables, you don't overwrite something special by mistake; `for path in /dir/*` doesn't break anything, but `for PATH in /dir/*` does)

Comment: Anyhow -- `wait` waits for all the `ssh` processes that were started in the background to exit. Mind, if you wanted to kill them explicitly, you could use `ssh ... & pids+=( "$!" )` to store the PIDs in an array, and then you could iterate over that array later to terminate any processes that are still running.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I kill these processes?

```
for HOST in $HOST_LOOP; do
   ssh $HOST 'kill ...the_process_that_plays_the_video'
done
```

---

The quick and dirty solution is to run `ssh -tt`, that will forward signals to process runnin gon the other side.

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel had exactly the same problem.

It was solved by making a wrapper, that checked if the `ssh` connection was still there and if not: killed the local job. https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_design.html#the-remote-system-wrapper

So maybe you can do:

```
# GNU Parallel wants hosts as: "host,host,host" not as "host host host"
hosts=$(echo "$HOST_LOOP" | perl -pe 's/ /,/g')
parallel -j0 -S"$hosts" --nonall play video
```

If this does not kill the job, try changing `--termseq`.